# Rewrite issue with configuring Lighttpd with Flask Python framework

Tags: python, configuration, url-rewriting, lighttpd, flask

I've run and developed my Flask application without incident using its built-in server. It has worked fine and has been really smooth and fun. Unfortunately, Lighttpd is, as always, a pain to deploy to. I'm following the instructions as closely as I can, but unfortunately, my application still isn't working out.

Here is my configuration so far:

```
server.modules   += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
server.modules   += ( "mod_rewrite" )

fastcgi.server = ("/bioinfo/main.fcgi" =>
    ((
        "socket" => "/tmp/bioinfo-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/bioinfo/main.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))
)
fastcgi.debug = 1

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/bioinfo/static/(.*)$" => "/bioinfo/static/$1",
    "^/bioinfo/(.*)$" => "/bioinfo/main.fcgi/$1"
)

# in: /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-fastcgi.conf
```

This works in that it displays the main page, but not any subsequent pages.

I have several app.route handlers in my Flask application which I access using either GET or POST using some XHR in the client.

Also, here's my .fcgi file, just to make sure I don't have any glaring errors here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from main import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

If anyone can identify the problem, being, AJAX doesn't work with the application's URIs (most likely because my rewrite rules are wonky), I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance, folks!

Comment: did you get ajax working with this configuration?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it was a very finicky setup. It wouldn't work 100% of the time. Hopefully Flask 0.8 will have worked this out by now, but I cannot revisit this project at this time. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to chdir to the directory your application is running in manually.

Answer (score 0):

I know this response comes from significantly in the future, but I ran into a similar issue and found that the fix for me was to make sure I was using `url_for` in my templates.
Hope that you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  For me the solution was to add this in the fcgi file,
just before the main function:

```
class ScriptNameStripper(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = ScriptNameStripper(app)
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test.